# Design request - Can I please have the visited questions in a different color?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bug, status-completed, design

I thought I wouldn't like the new design, but what I can I say? I looove it! And I'm not gotta grow tired of it this soon. But...There's something that bothers me.

---

I'm used to sleeping every night. (Who doesn't?!) The next day, I come and wanna check what questions I missed. I'll upvote the interesting questions, edit some of them and other questions, downvote @santiago's questions<sup>1</sup>, downvote the very poor ones etc. So, as I don't wanna create a tl;dr version and I wanna make the story short, someone like me would find **a different color on the titles of the questions that I visited** (i.e.  the visited links on the questions tab with another distinguishable color from the questions I didn't visit) very very handy.

As the default design of betas before graduation had this color difference, I *know* how useful it is for a contributor to know what stuff he'd dealt with and what stuff he hadn't yet. I'd like this implemented, please? Hope I'm not too late and the design team will respond.

I also tag this discussion, so if anyone had an idea about what color would be better, they could chip in. I myself am not recommending a special color, but as user experience experts, I know the design team would choose something bluish.

---

<sub>1: Don't take this one **that** seriously...</sub>

Comment: As long as it is not hot pink, I am okay with this

Comment: Thanks @santiago, that's a good color recommendation...

Comment: noooooooooooooooooo!!!!

Comment: You should leave a comment to this question in the announcement thread, for Kurtis to see.

Comment: Oh, good suggestion! Thanks Martin - (some Japanese words)!

Comment: All right. Just give us a day or two. It's on the list.

Comment: Tanks @Kurtis! All I needed to know!

Comment: Thanks Kurtis! Looks great now.

Comment: Can we have it so that the question reverts to the unread colour when a change is made? Now I have the problem that I read the questions and then later come back and want to read the answers but there is no way of telling which questions have been answered.

Comment: @bon Every time a question or answer is written or modified, it gets bumped up to the top of the pile, so you can get an idea if there's something new for you by looking at all the recent posts since you last visited, as well as the questions surrounding the one you're interested in. Is this not essentially equivalent?

Comment: Also, as an addition to the 'active' tab @Nicolau mentioned, every question in the questions' tab shows how many answers it got. I think that would suffice.

Comment: Thanks @Kurtis. Though, I am a little sad that is was not hot pink.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should be a (hopefully) simple style sheet change. Meta is already doing it, and other sites are also. The effect is generally subtle and I approve of subtle:

[image: screenshot of meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com highlighting the style sheet differences between links and visited links]

[image: screenshot of academia.stackexchange.com highlighting the style sheet differences between links and visited links]

$\color{magenta}{\text{I fully support subtle variations of hot pink}}$.

Comment: Hehe.... I would better ping santiago, but it'd be funnier if he sees this himself. And yes, I think introducing a different color for `a:visited` might do, hopefully.

Comment: I sense a disturbance in the force

Comment: As it turns out, green and pink are complementary colours, so a quick RGB inversion of the site design yields [quite the charming palette](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ubXXw.png).

Comment: I love it even more!

Comment: I love pink, and the inverted screenshot just looks absolutely awesome!

Comment: Have to admit - it actually looks good and my eyes are not burning as much as I thought

Comment: I want Nicolau Saker Neto’s picture as colour palette for chemistry.SX!